# Display items after fetching API after chosing Option from Selct menu

Tags: javascript, forms, compare, fetch-api

My HTML:

```
  <body>
    <form name="slectMovie">
      IMDb rating:
      <button type="submit" value="Select">Select</button>
    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

My JS:

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://134.209.87.8:1337/api/movies");
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    const imdbSelect = document.createElement("select");
    document.querySelector("form").append(imdbSelect);

    if (data.data.length > 0) {
      const IMDbRating = [
        ...new Set(data.data.map((x) => x.attributes.IMDbRating)),
      ];

      IMDbRating.forEach((category) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = category;
        imdbSelect.append(option);
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

getData();
```

I have one selection, that is movie rating, that I'm fetching from created API, and adding option values from API.

I would like to know how do I display items underneath form  that are only selected in select tag.

For example if I chose first option, I would like to display items underneath form that only match that criteria, if I chose other option to display only itmes that have that option criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to achieve this. below is one of these.

In The html, add new line to display the items.

```
<form name="slectMovie">
      IMDb rating:
      <button type="submit" value="Select">Select</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="theList"></ul>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

in javascript add few lines for display functionality

```
let data = [];
      function dispplayData({ target }) {
        const selectedItem = data.data.filter(
          (d) => d.attributes.IMDbRating === Number(target.value)
        );
        const displayList = document.querySelector("#theList");
        displayList.innerHTML = "";
        selectedItem.forEach((item) => {
          let listItem = document.createElement("li");
          listItem.textContent = item.attributes.title;
          displayList.appendChild(listItem);
        });
        console.log(selectedItem);
      }

      const getData = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await fetch("http://134.209.87.8:1337/api/movies");
          data = await res.json();
          console.log(data);
          const imdbSelect = document.createElement("select");
          document.querySelector("form").append(imdbSelect);
          imdbSelect.addEventListener("change", dispplayData);

          if (data.data.length > 0) {
            const IMDbRating = [
              ...new Set(data.data.map((x) => x.attributes.IMDbRating)),
            ];

            IMDbRating.forEach((category) => {
              const option = document.createElement("option");
              option.textContent = category;
              imdbSelect.append(option);
            });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };

      getData();
```

Hope this helps you.